# Use parent values in subquery [SOLVED]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem.
How can I use a parent attribute in a subquery select?

Example

```
Record A
id: 1
parent_id: 1
name: Test A

Record B
id: 2
parent_id: 1
name: Test B

Record c
id: 3
parent_id: 2
name: Test c
```

Query result:
[{name: 'Test A', total: 2}, {name: 'Test B', total: 2}, {name: 'Test C', total: 1}]

I have this query

```
Record.select('(select COUNT(*) from records where records.parent_id = parent_id), name')
```

but this gets the total of all records, only works if I set the id for example

```
Record.select('(select COUNT(*) from records where records.parent_id = 2), name')
```

Comment: How did you solve it?, Mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Writing the desired formatting directly within the query itself can be complex. Instead, you can retrieve the count using the query and format the result using Ruby code.

```
records = Record.group(:parent_id).select("group_concat(name) as names, count(*) as total")
res = []
records.each do |record|
  name_arr = record['names'].split(",")
  res << name_arr.map{|name| {'name' => name, 'total' => record['total']}}
end
return res
```